# Transferring variable from userform in the itemsend routine in outlook

Tags: vba, input, outlook, userform

currently, I have a routine in outlook that is run when I send and email.

The object of the code is to automatically CC a person in organization A whenever I email person B. That being said, I have a userform with radio buttons that have the 4 people in organization A so I can select them to be CCd when I send the email.

When I click send I can get the userform to open and assign the correct value to the variable based on what button I click on the userform.

However, I cannot get this value to transfer back to the itemsend routine once I click OK the userform subroutine. Below is the code:

From the userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

            Dim strBcc As String
            If option1.Value = True Then
            strBcc = "xxx@xxxx.com"
            End If
End Sub
Set frm = New userfrm
            frm.show
```

From the item send:

```
Set frm = New userfrm
            frm.show
```

Once is tell the itemsend to show my userform, how do I transfer that input back to the itemsend routine?

Answer (score 0):

The property will be set on the item. You should be able to access it using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. To see the actual DASL property name, look at the item in the Sent Items folder with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, select the property in question, look at the DASL edit box.

Answer (score 0):

In CommandButton1_Click hide the form. No other code.

In ItemSend

```
If frm.option1.Value = True Then
    strBcc = "xxx@xxxx.com"
```